# Azure web app service for Linux containers not picking up environment variables from docker-compose file

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am not sure if I misunderstand how this should work.

I have a docker compose file (below) that defines environment variable for a single "service"/image:

```
services:
  webui:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/WebUI/Dockerfile
    environment:
      UseInMemoryDatabase: false
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+:443;http://+:80
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "********************************"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    restart: always
```

When I open kudu for the web app and look at the environment tag, NONE of the environment variables defined above are present.

I manually set them by going to **azure app -> configuration - --> application settings** and add a record for each of the env variables above.
I can restart the app and I can now see the variables listed in the **azure app -> Advance tools -> Kudu -> environment -> AppSettings**

I also had to add the connection string to the separate connection strings settings of the azure app portal.

### QUESTION:

Am I understanding this correctly?  Should the app service "see" my environment variables in my docker-compose file and add them to the app settings for the running app service?  Or is it normal to have to define each of those variables a second time in the configuration of the azure app service?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not correct. The environment variables in the app settings are only accessible when the Web App is in the running state. Currently, it does not support to set custom variables in the docker-compose file. As I know, there are only serial variables set by Azure that can be used in the docker-compose file, such as the variable [`WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#modify-configuration-file). But for the image option, it does not support.

Comment: thanks charles, this is my first real attempt at docker and azure ci/cd.  THe real problem I am having is that my container image runs and exposes port http 5000,https: 5001.  But the azure app service does not open those ports to the web so the web app times out.  THere is a disconnect between the service and the image.  Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @JKing You can only expose one port to outside and it should be 80 or 443 in Azure Web App. If you export your web app uses another port, you need to set the environment variable [`WEBSITES_PORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#you-can-only-expose-one-port-to-the-outside-worldapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your environment variables correctly in your compose file.  App Service will inject them in your container so no need to duplicate them as App Settings.

What's strange is that if you look at the docker run command in the startup logs, they are not passed as parameters and also, they are not listed in the Environment page in Kudu.  That threw me off but I did a test using the Kuard image and was able to see my env var.